# Generating logic vector in a new data frame column based on two sets of target values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame in the form of:

```
exampleCurrent <- data.frame(value = c(5, 4.5, 3, 2.9, 1.5),
             off = as.logical(c("F", "F", "T", "T", "F")),
             hiOnTarget = c(5.5, 4, 5, 4.7, 4),
             loOnTarget =c(4, 3, 3, 4, 3),
             hiOffTarget = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3),
             lowOffTarget = c(1, 2, 1, 1.2, 2))
```

The context of the data is a measured `value`, and a logical statement as to if it is a workday or an 'off' day (i.e. a weekend or holiday).

The `Target` values are calculated variables that identify if the measured value should be considered extreme (in other words, an outlier). A `value` between these two targets is considered normal, a 'value' which is above the `hiTarget` or below the `loTarget` is considered extreme.

If `off` is `False` (i.e. 'On'), the `value` is assessed to see if it is between `hiOnTarget`and `loOnTarget`.  If `off` is `True`, the `value` needs to be measured against the `hiOffTarget` and `loOffTarget`

I would like to get to the following:

```
exampleWanted <- data.frame(value = c(5, 4.5, 3, 2.9, 1.5),
                        off = as.logical(c("F", "F", "T", "T", "F")),
                        hiOnTarget = c(5.5, 4, 5, 4.7, 4),
                        loOnTarget =c(4, 3, 3, 4, 3),
                        hiOffTarget = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3),
                        lowOffTarget = c(1, 2, 1, 1.2, 2),
                        extremeValue = as.logical(c("F", "T", "F", "T", "T")))
```

My attempts to generate the sixth column, `extremeValue`, have been centered on `if(){}else{}` style logical statements, the closest of which is currently:

```
 exampleWanted <- if( exampleCurrent$value > exampleCurrent$hiOnTarget | exampleCurrent$value > exampleCurrent$loOnTarget) {
    exampleWanted <-"True"
    } else {
        exampleWanted <-"False"}
```

I've obviously only got half way here as this will blindly assess the calculation as entirely 'on', however I can't even get this part to work. I am planning to use `switch()` to toggle between two similar `if(){}else{}` commands, though totally alternative solutions would be fine.

N.B. This is a small part the first major R script I've ever written outside of a tutorial, so apologies for what is probably practically a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest thing to do is to create an intermediate object of the relevant targets. This is just two lines, and it's easy to read and understand

```
relevantTarget <- 
  data.frame(hi=with(exampleCurrent, ifelse(off, hiOffTarget, hiOnTarget)),
             lo=with(exampleCurrent, ifelse(off, lowOffTarget, loOnTarget)))

exampleCurrent$extremeValue <-
  with(exampleCurrent, value < relevantTarget$lo | value > relevantTarget$hi)
```

Comment: Or a variation is `transform(exampleCurrent, extremeValue=value > off*hiOffTarget+ (!off)*hiOnTarget| value < off*lowOffTarget+(!off)*loOnTarget)`

Comment: @arvi1000, this works, and I think I understand most of it. However, I'm confused about the inclusion of `with`. R-help states:

Evaluate an R expression in an environment constructed from data, possibly modifying (a copy of) the original data.

To my poor understanding I thought that was what R was doing anyway?

Comment: here, `with(data_frame_name, expression)` is just a way to tidy up the code. in order to avoid repeating `data_frame_name`, we say 'all the objects in `expression` are components of that data.frame'. So, `with(exampleCurrent, ifelse(off, hiOffTarget, hiOnTarget))` is the same as `ifelse(exampleCurrent$off, exampleCurrent$hiOffTarget, exampleCurrent$hiOnTarget`)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by  using the logical index column `exampleCurrent$off` to subset the rows, while concerned columns are subsetted based on their numeric index or column names.  Check whether the "value" lies between the "Target" columns and assign the logical index to the "extremeValue" column.

```
exampleCurrent$extremeValue <- FALSE
indx <- exampleCurrent$off
exampleCurrent$extremeValue[!indx] <-with(exampleCurrent[!indx, c(1,3:4)], 
           !(value >= loOnTarget & value < hiOnTarget))
exampleCurrent$extremeValue[indx] <-with(exampleCurrent[indx, c(1,5:6)],
    !(value >= lowOffTarget & value < hiOffTarget))

 identical(exampleCurrent, exampleWanted)
 #[1] TRUE
```